# SQL Access Denied

Tags: mysql, database, authorization

I'm working through tutorials in the book 'Cloning internet apps w/ Ruby.' I've made web apps before but they depended on sqlite and now I have to use mysql.

I've installed community server but when I try to create a database using the command line I'm receiving the error message listed above.

```
$ mysql 

mysql> create database tinyclone;
```

Returns

ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'p'

Notes:

- The mysql command-line client flashes open and immediately closes, so I'm accessing it from the command prompt.
- I've installed and uninstalled mysql several times in attempts to figure out this problem. In the latest install, I didn't set a password.
- I'm aware that this line should probably be '`$mysql -u <username> -p <password>`' but I didn't set a password and I'm not sure what the username would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the user is `root`

If you havn't set a password, use `$ mysql -u root`

Comment: Good stuff. If you want to check, while you're still at the mysql prompt, do `show databases;`

Answer (score 2):

The default MySQL username is 'root', try that without a password

Comment: Thanks for the quick response I tried.

'mysql root'

And it returned the same access denied code but without giving me a 'mysql>' prompt

Answer (score 1):

The default username for MySQL is `root`, so you can try by

```
$ mysql -u root
```

by default it logs you with your Linux account. If you're logged as `root` on your Linux machine it will be OK just using `$ mysql`